# Automorphic forms and Galois representations over imaginary quadratic fields: generalizing Taylor's theorem?

Tags: automorphic-forms, galois-representations, nt.number-theory

Let $K/\mathbf{Q}$ be an imaginary quadratic field, with $\sigma \in \mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbf{Q})$ a generator. Suppose $\pi$ is a cuspidal automorphic representation of $GL_2 / K$ with central character $\omega_{\pi}$.  If $\pi_{\infty}$ has Langlands parameter $z\to \mathrm{diag}(z^{1-k},\overline{z}^{1-k})$ for $k \geq 2$ an integer, and $\omega_{\pi}^{\sigma}=\omega_{\pi}$, then a well-known theorem of Taylor (proved in the early 90's) yields a compatible system of two-dimensional $\ell$-adic Galois representations of $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$ attached to $\pi$.  My question is simple: given all the recent work on the fundamental lemma and concomitant progress in the field of automorphic Galois representations, it is yet possible to prove this result *without* any Galois-invariance assumption on the central character $\omega_{\pi}$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Various groups of people have thought about/are thinking about this.  The natural source of the desired Galois reps. is a $U(2,2)$ Shimura variety.  The problem is that the cohomology of this variety is not so easy to understand.  The fundamental lemma certainly plays some role in controlling it, but I don't think that by itself it overcomes the key difficulties.  (My own understanding of the issues is far from perfect, though.)

Comment: Ah, interesting!  What, precisely, is the natural way of moving to this Shimura variety?  The form $\pi \otimes \pi^{\sigma}$ is conjugate self-dual, so should transfer, but it's not obvious to me that you could easily recover $\rho_{\pi}$ from a tensor product like this.  Or am I on the wrong track?

Comment: If one constructs a quasi-split $GU(2,2)$ from the quad. imag. field $K$, then the hyperbolic $3$-manifolds that arise as congruence quotients for $\mathrm{GL}_2(K)$ appear in the Borel--Serre boundary of the Shimura varieties for $GU(2,2)$.

Comment: Okay, but don't you get Eisenstein cohomology classes in this manner?  Is it obvious that they're congruent modulo $\ell$-powers to cuspidal classes (which is what one would hope for in order to use pseudo-representations)?  Thanks for your patience; I feel I'm missing something fundamental here.

Comment: No, it is not obvious, and therein lies the difficulty.

Answer (score 3):

Taylor's theorem is about *regular algebraic* representations $\pi$. Most representations are not algebraic in any sense (cf. my answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/50581/)), hence they are not connected to any Galois representation (as far as we know).

Now for an algebraic $\pi$ the question arises where to look for the corresponding Galois representation. The difficulty with $GL_2/K$ is that the corresponding symmetric space is not an algebraic variety, hence there is no cohomology which would carry the relevant Galois representation. Taylor's idea was to pass to $GSp_4/\mathbb{Q}$ which is better in that regard, but the switch requires the condition on the central character. My feeling is that what is missing is a better (more general) construction yielding an object with a Galois action, not a better understanding of the fundamental lemma or Galois representations per se. This is not my field of expertise, so I better stop here.

Comment: My first paragraph was no criticism, I just wanted to emphasize the initial algebraic nature of $\pi$.