# Strong automorphisms of the Selberg class

Tags: nt.number-theory, selberg-class

Following [Automorphisms of the Selberg class](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/50581/automorphisms-of-the-selberg-class), I define **strong** automorphisms of the Selberg class by adding as an hypothesis that every invariant of $F$ (i.e all the $H$-invariants, conductor and root number, not only the degree) is preserved under the action of such a strong automorphism. It follows that (see [http://www.math.ubc.ca/~gerg/teaching/613-Winter2011/SelbergClass.pdf](http://www.math.ubc.ca/%7Egerg/teaching/613-Winter2011/SelbergClass.pdf)), if $\Phi$ is a strong automorphism of $\mathcal{S}$, then for every $F\in\mathcal{S}$, $F$ and $\Phi(F)$ have the same functional equation.

My question is: can there be other strong automorphisms of the Selberg class than the identity map and the complex conjugation?

Thanks in advance.

Edit January 13th, 2021: a more natural requirement would be that $F$ belongs to the Selberg class and thus fulfills the axioms defining it iff $\Phi(F)$ does too. This implies that the root number $\varepsilon_{F}$ of $F$ is sent to $\varepsilon_{\Phi(F)}$ by a map $\Phi^{*}$ associated to $\Phi$. Moreover, the fact that both $F$ and $\Phi(F)$ can be written as an Euler product should imply that $\Phi$ is completely multiplicative. Does it imply some notion of continuity for $\Phi^{*}$ entailing that only two different automorphisms of $\mathcal{S}$ can exist?

Edit May 11th 2021: if I'm not mistaken, $\Phi^{*}$ sending a root number to a root number makes it an automorphism of the unit circle, which should provide an affirmative answer to the question in the previous edit. This may also show that the symmetry group of the functional equation of any given $F$ is of order at most $2$.